# Basic java re-factoring: Delegate the differences of child classes to parent and merge/remove them

Tags: java, design-patterns, refactoring, abstract, final

Please deal with this basic question.

I have an `abstract class C1` which extends another `abstract class C0` and is extended by multiple `sub-classes (C21 and C22)`.

```
@Component
public abstract class C0 {
    protected abstract String getCaller();  
//Some other methods.
}
```

.

```
public abstract class C1 extends C0 {
//Set of methods which are used by children and then calls methods of C0 which then use getCaller();
}
```

.

```
    @Controller
    public class C21 extends C1 {

    @RequestMapping(value = "abc", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String start(@RequestParam(value = "kw", required = true) String p1,
            @RequestParam(value = Constant.REQUEST_PARAM_KEYWORDID, required = true) long p2) throws Exception {
//Some processing and calls controllers defined in abstract class C1
        return "200";
    }


    @Override
    protected String getCaller() {
        return "C21";
    }

}
```

.

```
@Controller
public class C22 extends C1 {

    @RequestMapping(value = "abc", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String start(@RequestParam(value = "kw", required = true) String p1,
            @RequestParam(value = Constant.REQUEST_PARAM_KEYWORDID, required = true) long p2) throws Exception {
//Some processing and calls controllers defined in abstract class C1
        return "200";
    }


    @Override
    protected String getCaller() {
        return "C22";
    }

}
```

C0 contains an abstract method `getCaller();` Callers of C21 and C22 are different but they can be identified by the parameter passed to only method `start(p1,p2)` of these classes.

`start(p1,p2)` does similar thing in both the classes. Only difference in C21 and C22 is the implementation of `getCaller()` which is fixed and can anyways be extracted from parameters of start. So, I decided to create single class instead of C21 and C22.

I cannot create `setCaller()` so, I wanted to create a `final method` and a private variable `caller` in abstract `class C1` which could be populated with the parameters of `start` method and returned in `getCaller()` (which is called from `abstract class C0`).

Is this the correct approach? Is there any better way or pattern for this?

Comment: Please outline the actual code. It's much clearer that way than your abstract description.

Comment: Why does this question deserve a downvote?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Only difference in C21 and C22 is the implementation of getCaller() which is fixed and can anyways be extracted from parameters of start.

Since you have to change only a single method, you will be better off with a single non-abstract implementation `C1` instead of an abstract `C1` and a pair of `C21` and `C22`. You can do something like this:

```
Caller caller;
public start(SomeType1 p1, SomeType2 p2, SomeType3 p3) {
    caller = new Caller(p1, p2, p3);
    ...
    // Do other stuff
}

public Caller getCaller() {
    return caller;
}
```

In case there are other classes in addition to `C21` and `C22` inheriting `C1`, you may want to keep your `C1` abstract, and add a non-abstract `C2` with an above implementation.